# ¿Se puede aplicar la función .mask a una variable con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un input con la siguiente función jQuery ".mask"

```
 $('#txtOtroCantidad').mask('000,000,000.00', { reverse: true });
```

Mi idea es poder aplicar esa función mask a una variable, que quede más o menos de ésta manera:

```
var MontoOriginal = $('#txtMonto').val();
var mascara = MontoOriginal.mask('000,000,000.00', { reverse: true });
```

El valor de la variable 'mascara' no toma el formato de .mask, alguna solución?

Comment: `.mask()` es para dar formatos especiales a inputs o elementos de html, por lo que la función solo sirve para objetos de jQuery, `MontoOriginal` es solo un string, no puedes aplicarle esa función. Si `MontoOriginal` lo dejas como `$('#txtMonto')` sin el `.val()` si funcionará

Comment: El problema es que coges el valor y luego tratas de aplicar la mascara al string como dice @lixus. lo que tienes que hacer es aplicar la mascara y coger despues el valor .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No se cual plugin mask utilizas pero haciendolo general, puedes hacerlo creando un elemento temporal, aplicar el mask a ese elemento y luego obtener el valor del elemento con el `.mask` aplicado:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#aplicarMascara").click(function(){
            var MontoOriginal = $('#txtMonto').val();

             var tempInput = $(document.createElement("input"));
             tempInput.val(MontoOriginal);
             tempInput.mask('000,000,000.00', { reverse: true });
             var mascara = tempInput.val();
             console.log(mascara);   
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input id="txtMonto" value="999999999" />
<input type="button" value="Aplicar Mascara variable" id="aplicarMascara" />
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me sirvió de mucho, es justo lo que necesitaba.

Comment: Me alegra haberte ayudado.

Comment: @OscarNavarro recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta. Ambos ganais rep ;)

Comment: Cierto, muchas gracias por recordarlo, se me había pasado @lois6b